# Additional information in DNS query with dig

Tags: domain-name-system

I read that the additional secition part of a DNS packet is just used for the response. That means it should be empty in the query. But when I run a normal dig command (`dig google.com`) and then have a look at the packet that was sent (with wireshark) I recognize that the additional information section isn't empty (I'm sure I looked up the query not the response).

[Here you can see the content of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58EON.png)

When I run the same with drill (`drill google.com`) the additional information section is empty as I thiught it should be.

Can you explain me the meaning of this additional information in the section?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're reading is slightly dated. The Additional section is also used to wrap the [EDNS0 pseudo-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_mechanisms_for_DNS), and you can see in your packet capture where it specifies `EDNS0 version: 0`. `Option: Cookie` specifies that this is a [DNS cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7873). The Additional section was used for this purpose because it was possible to make older clients ignore this data without rejecting the datagram. It uses a pseudo record type called `OPT` that will be ignored per when not recognized.

The difference you are observing is that your version of the dig command populates that option field, but drill does not.

Comment: That means modern DNS servers can ignore this additional information?

Comment: All DNS servers can ignore this information, modern or otherwise. Modern ones are of course more likely to implement the EDNS0 features being requested by the client.